# Adjusting logging programmatically in Jetty 11

Tags: jetty, slf4j

Jetty changed how logging works between 9 and 10/11. It used to be possible to pass a logger via `org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.setLog()`, which has now been deprecated. It appears to be non-functional rather than deprecated, as there is a comment that says `// does nothing` in the body of that method. Sadly there is nothing there pointing to a solution.

So, how can one programmatically adjust logging in Jetty 11?

Answer (score 0):

Jetty uses slf4j now.

https://www.slf4j.org/

You have to pick a logging implementation first.  You have many many choices here.

See ...

```java
$ cd /path/to/my-jetty-base
$ java -jar /path/to/jetty-home/start.jar --list-module=logging

Modules [logging]:
==================

logging modules:
----------------
       console-capture - Redirects the JVM console stderr and stdout to a rolling log file.
   logging-jcl-capture - Captures jakarta-commons-logging events and bridges them to SLF4J.
         logging-jetty - Base configuration for the jetty logging mechanism.
           logging-jul - Configures jetty logging to use Java Util Logging (jul).
   logging-jul-capture - Captures java.util.logging events and bridges them to slf4j.
        logging-log4j1 - Configures Jetty logging to use Log4j.
logging-log4j1-capture - Captures Apache log4j events and bridges them to SLF4J.
        logging-log4j2 - Configures Jetty logging to use log4j version 2.
       logging-logback - Configures Jetty logging to use Logback Logging.
          logging-noop - Configures Jetty logging to use SLF4J No-Op Implementation.
         logging/slf4j - Configures logging to use SLF4J.
```

Once that implementation has been chosen, then you adjust the configuration within that logging implementation.

If you were using a custom logging implementation in the past, you will have to adjust to be a custom logging appender implementation in a specific logging implementation now.

Most logging implementations in the list above support this, just don't use the `logging-noop`, or `logging-jetty` implementations if that is what you are after (neither of those support custom appenders).